# Differences between UINavigationController's Left Edge Swipe and Back Button behaviour

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, gestures

I'm trying to figure out the difference between a navigation controller's left edge swipe and back button behavior. I have a bug that only occurs when the you navigate back through a left edge swipe. If you press the back button it works correctly. Nothing custom is being done to enable or disable the back navigation or gesture navigation.

I have found surprisingly few resources on this topic and I'd just like a more thorough understanding of what events are triggered by each, and how behaviourally they are different.

Comment: Will need a lot more detail then just this.. What happens exactly? What do you see different from the left edge swipe and the back button? Can you show some code related to the bug (form both related viewcontrollers)

Comment: One of the differences is that the left edge swipe is an interactive transition, e.g. user can control the speed and direction - moving back and force, and also can cancel the transition, while tapping on the back button is not.

Answer (score 3):

Does this bug manifest itself all the time, or does it manifest itself if and only if you start a left edge swipe and cancel it? The reason I ask is that we used to write code that assumed that `viewWillAppear` of the prior VC and `viewWillDisappear` of the current one would always precede `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidDisappear`, respectively. But this is no longer true with interactive transitions, because `viewWillAppear`/`Disappear` will be called when you start a transition, but the corresponding `viewDidAppear`/`Disappear` may not if the interactive transition is cancelled. In fact, when introducing this concept at WWDC 2013, the presenter joked that they should rename `viewWillAppear` to "`viewMightAppear`, or `viewWillProbablyAppear`, or `iReallyWishThisViewWouldAppear`".

So, take a look at your `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` methods and make sure you don't have anything there which is dependent upon the view actually appearing and disappearing, respectively, because if the gesture is canceled, you won't see those events.

For more information, see WWDC 2013 video [Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/218/). Interactive transitions is discussed a little more than half way through the video. It discusses how to implement your own interactive transitions, but the concepts apply to the built-in left-edge swipe of the navigation controller.

---

In a standard "back" button process, popping from the second view controller to the first one, the sequence of events is the typical:

- `SecondViewController.viewWillDisappear`
- `FirstViewController.viewWillAppear`
- `SecondViewController.viewDidDisappear`
- `FirstViewController.viewDidAppear`

But if you start a left-edge swipe gesture and pause, the sequence of events is:

- `SecondViewController.viewWillDisappear`
- `FirstViewController.viewWillAppear`

But if you stop the gesture and cancel the transition, rather than seeing the `SecondViewController.viewDidDisappear` and `FirstViewController.viewDidAppear`, you will see the following events:

- `FirstViewController.viewWillDisappear`
- `FirstViewController.viewDidDisappear`
- `SecondViewController.viewWillAppear`
- `SecondViewController.viewDidAppear`

Depending upon what you're doing in these various "appear" related methods, you can have problems if it's not done correctly. For example, if you're doing some cleanup in `viewWillDisappear`, make sure you're only cleaning up things that you set up in `viewWillAppear`. Or if you're doing anything in `viewDidAppear`, make sure you won't have problems if that method is called again if the interactive transition is cancelled. It's impossible to say what precisely is wrong in your situation without information about what you're doing in these appear-related methods.

But the bottom line is that you just need to make sure that the app isn't making any assumptions that just because a transition started, that it will have necessarily finish.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this issue, if someone is removing a view controller from the navigation stack or changing it in any other way, please do this kind of logic in viewDidAppear, because placing that logic somewhere else messes up the back button and left-to-right swipe gesture completely. Placing that logic in viewDidAppear will fix your problems.